# validation in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, validation

I'm making a litte todo app with angular.

in my component.html i want a validation. If you enter nothing in the textbox then i text is show with "title is required". And when you have less then 5 characters in the textbox then also a text is showing.

But that doesn't work ..

When i start my app i see only my textbox without my todo's. When i enter 1 letter in the textbox then i see my todos. Also when i have only 4 characters i see no notification that says i must have 5 characters ..

This is my code :

```
    <h3>Add todo</h3>
<form >

  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="text" required minlength="5" [(ngModel)]="text" name="text" >
  <div *ngIf="text.errors && (text.dirty || text.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!text.errors.required">
      Title is required 
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!text.errors.minlength">
      titel moet minstens 5 karakters zijn
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="addTodo()">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the template reference with `ngModel` to bind the error messages. Like so: `#text="ngModel"`.

The two-way-binding won't work with the same name, so they have to be different. Here I have actually changed the name of the two-way-binding variable to `theText`:

```
<input type="text" id="text" required minlength="5" [(ngModel)]="theText" 
         name="text" #text="ngModel">
```

Here's the complete template, notice we are giving the form a template reference `#myForm="ngForm"` and on submit we pass the values from that form:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(myForm.value)">
  <input type="text" id="text" required minlength="5" [(ngModel)]="theText" name="text" #text="ngModel" >
    <div *ngIf="text.errors && (text.touched || text.dirty)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div [hidden]="!text.errors?.required">
        Title is required 
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="!text.errors?.minlength">
        titel moet minstens 5 karakters zijn
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As a sidenote, you maybe even don't need the two-way-binding (??) here? You could extract the data from the object you get of the form values (`myForm.value`).